# can someone help me, installing artoolkit on ubuntu 12.04 and ros hydro

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I tried to install ARToolKit with the ar_pose package on Ubuntu 12.04.3 64 bit. Can someone help me to install artoolkit?
I tried to install ccny_mav_tool and ccny_vision but the sites are not available.

```
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/afeldmann/ros/ar_tools/artoolkit/build/artoolkit/lib/SRC/Gl'
cc -c -O -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic/include -I../../../include gsub.c
ar rs ../../libARgsub.a gsub.o
rm -f gsub.o
cc -c -O -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic/include -I../../../include gsubUtil.c
In file included from ../../../include/AR/sys/videoLinuxV4L.h:23:0,
                 from ../../../include/AR/video.h:102,
                 from gsubUtil.c:19:
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic/include/linux/types.h:14:26: error: conflicting types for ‘fd_set’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/select.h:76:5: note: previous declaration of ‘fd_set’ was here
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic/include/linux/types.h:15:25: error: conflicting types for ‘dev_t’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:61:17: note: previous declaration of ‘dev_t’ was here
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic/include/linux/types.h:19:17: error: conflicting types for ‘nlink_t’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:76:19: note: previous declaration of ‘nlink_t’ was here
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic/include/linux/types.h:25:26: error: conflicting types for ‘timer_t’
/usr/include/time.h:104:19: note: previous declaration of ‘timer_t’ was here
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic/include/linux/types.h:45:26: error: conflicting types for ‘loff_t’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:45:18: note: previous declaration of ‘loff_t’ was here
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic/include/linux/types.h:111:17: error: conflicting types for ‘uint64_t’
/usr/include/stdint.h:56:27: note: previous declaration of ‘uint64_t’ was here
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic/include/linux/types.h:112:17: error: conflicting types for ‘u_int64_t’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:204:1: note: previous declaration of ‘u_int64_t’ was here
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic/include/linux/types.h:113:17: error: conflicting types for ‘int64_t’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:198:1: note: previous declaration of ‘int64_t’ was here
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic/include/linux/types.h:134:23: error: conflicting types for ‘blkcnt_t’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:236:20: note: previous declaration of ‘blkcnt_t’ was here
make[3]: *** [../../libARgsubUtil.a(gsubUtil.o)] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/afeldmann/ros/ar_tools/artoolkit/build/artoolkit/lib/SRC/Gl'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/afeldmann/ros/ar_tools/artoolkit/build/artoolkit/lib/SRC'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/afeldmann/ros/ar_tools/artoolkit/build/artoolkit'
make: *** [installed] Error 2
afeldmann@Lapi:~/ros$ cd
afeldmann@Lapi:~$ echo "make[3]: Entering directory `/home/afeldmann/ros/ar_tools/artoolkit/build/artoolkit/lib/SRC/Gl'"
cc -c -O -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic/include -I../../../include gsub.c ar rs ../../libARgsub.a gsub.o rm -f gsub.o cc -c -O -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic/include -I../../../include gsubUtil.c In file included from ../../../include/AR/sys/videoLinuxV4L.h:23:0
                 from ../../../include/AR/video.h:102
                 from gsubUtil.c:19: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic/include/linux/types.h:14:26: error: conflicting types for ‘fd_set’ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/select.h:76:5: note: previous declaration of ‘fd_set’ was here /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic/include/linux/types.h:15:25: error: conflicting types for ‘dev_t’ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:61:17: note: previous declaration of ‘dev_t’ was here /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic/include/linux/types.h:19:17: error: conflicting types for ‘nlink_t’ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:76:19: note: previous declaration of ‘nlink_t’ was here /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic/include/linux/types.h:25:26: error: conflicting types for ‘timer_t’ /usr/include/time.h:104:19: note: previous declaration of ‘timer_t’ was here /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic/include/linux/types.h:45:26: error: conflicting types for ‘loff_t’ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:45:18: note: previous declaration of ‘loff_t’ was here /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic/include/linux/types.h:111:17: error: conflicting types for ‘uint64_t’ /usr/include/stdint.h:56:27: note: previous declaration of ‘uint64_t’ was here /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic/include/linux/types.h:112:17: error: conflicting types for ‘u_int64_t’ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:204:1: note: previous declaration of ‘u_int64_t’ was here /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic/include/linux/types.h:113:17: error: conflicting types for ‘int64_t’ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:198:1: note: previous declaration of ‘int64_t’ was here /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic/include/linux/types.h:134:23: error: conflicting types for ‘blkcnt_t’ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:236:20: note: previous declaration of ‘blkcnt_t’ was here make[3]: *** [../../libARgsubUtil.a(gsubUtil.o)] Error 1
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/79841/can-someone-help-me,-installing-artoolkit-on-ubuntu-12.04-and-ros-hydro/) by [anton](https://answers.ros.org/users/6751/anton/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-09-16

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Open
   `./ar_tools/artoolkit/build/artoolkit/Configure`
2. Remove
   `-I/usr/src/linux-headers-"$(uname -r)"/include`
   from CFLAG line 79
3. Rebuild.

Original artoolkit doesn't have this problem. The source of the problem is the patch file https://github.com/IHeartEngineering/ar_tools/blob/master/artoolkit/patch_auto_config. On line 28 they added linux-heades for some reason. I've sent a pull request.

---

Originally posted by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) with karma: 709 on 2013-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [happylulu](https://answers.ros.org/users/15351/happylulu/) on 2014-04-29**:
error 404 to "https://github.com/IHeartEngineering/ar_tools/blob/master/artoolkit/patch_auto_config"...I have the same probleme...the git for fuerte is unavailable...anyone have the solution?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your errors are releated to the fact that you have two sets of linux kernel headers in your path that you are including.  In most cases you shouldn't be adding /usr/src/linux-headers* to your path.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1